# Why am I getting could not find a declaration file for module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shopify

Getting this error in my Shopify App. Possibly they

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-sticky-mouse-tooltip'. '/Users/jee/work/blah/node_modules/react-sticky-mouse-tooltip/dist/MouseTooltip.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-sticky-mouse-tooltip` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-sticky-mouse-tooltip';`ts(7016)
```

I added the following but didn't help.

```
typings > plugins.d.ts > declare module "react-sticky-mouse-tooltip";
```

Here is the package.js

```
{
  "name": "shopify-app-node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Shopify's node app for CLI tool",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon ./server/index.js --watch ./server/index.js",
    "build": "NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1 next build",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./server/index.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-node.git"
  },
  "author": "Shopify Inc.",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/shopify/shopify-app-node/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.12.10",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/register": "^7.12.10",
    "@shopify/app-bridge-react": "^2.0.2",
    "@shopify/app-bridge-utils": "^2.0.2",
    "@shopify/koa-shopify-auth": "^4.1.2",
    "@shopify/polaris": "^6.2.0",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "graphql": "^14.5.8",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "koa": "^2.13.1",
    "koa-router": "^10.0.0",
    "koa-session": "^6.1.0",
    "next": "^10.0.4",
    "next-env": "^1.1.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "react": "^16.10.1",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.1",
    "react-sticky-mouse-tooltip": "^0.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-stage-3": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "enzyme": "3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.15.5",
    "husky": "^4.3.6",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.0",
    "prettier": "2.2.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "15.6.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.14.0"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,css,json,md}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: did you npm install the types package? some older packages dont come bundled with types npm i --save-dev @types/react-sticky-mouse-tooltip

Comment: It does not have a types package.